# Checking if Cosmos Document DB Document exists using Core MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, azure-cosmosdb

I am getting a list of Azure blobs and then looping over the list. I am wanting to search Cosmos DB collection to see if the c.ImageFilename of the blob exists. If it does not exist add new record into Cosmos Collection.

This line is not retrieving Cosmos DB records:

var docExists = await _cosmosDbService.GetItemsAsync(item);

The section of CosmosDBService.cs is :

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<ANPRData>> GetItemsAsync(string queryString)
        {
            var query = this._container.GetItemQueryIterator<ANPRData>(new QueryDefinition(queryString));
            List<ANPRData> results = new List<ANPRData>();
            while (query.HasMoreResults)
            {
                var response = await query.ReadNextAsync();

                results.AddRange(response.ToList());
            }

            return results;
        }
```

Can you please help?

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 

// 

namespace WebApp_Storage_DotNet.Controllers
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.IO;
    using Microsoft.WindowsAzure;
    using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
    using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;
    using Microsoft.Azure;
    using System.Configuration;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
    using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth;
    using ANPR.Services;
    using ANPR.Models;

    public class UploadController : Controller
    {
        static CloudBlobClient blobClient;
        const string blobContainerName = "hvsimages";
        public string subFolder = "192-168-2-44/img/";
        static CloudBlobContainer blobContainer;
        public string accountName = "xxx";
        public string accountKey ="xxx";
        private ANPRData item;

        public readonly ICosmosDbService _cosmosDbService;
        public UploadController(ICosmosDbService cosmosDbService)
        {
            _cosmosDbService = cosmosDbService;
        }



        public async Task<ActionResult> Index() 
        {
            try
            {
                var account = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials(accountName, accountKey), true);

                blobClient = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
                blobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference(blobContainerName);

                List<Uri> allBlobs = new List<Uri>();

                var directory = blobContainer.GetDirectoryReference("192-168-2-44/img/");
                var result = await directory.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync(true, BlobListingDetails.None, 500, null, null, null);


                foreach (var dirItem in result.Results)
                {

                     string item = "SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.ImageFilename = '" + dirItem.Uri + "''";
                   var datas = await _cosmosDbService.GetItemsAsync(item);


                     Console.WriteLine(datas);


                    //  Console.WriteLine(docExists);

                    if (datas == null)
                    {
                        var Bing = "I am Not Empty";
                        Console.WriteLine(Bing);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var Bing = "I am Empty";
                        Console.WriteLine(Bing);
                    }

                        allBlobs.Add(dirItem.Uri);
                    }
                return View(allBlobs);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ViewData["message"] = ex.Message;
                ViewData["trace"] = ex.StackTrace;
                return View("Error");
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It ended up being as simple as the SQL statement.

```
 foreach (var dirItem in result.Results)
                {
                    string item = "SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.ImageFilename = '" + dirItem.Uri + "'";
                    var myQuery = await _cosmosDbService.ExistsDocument(item);

                    if (myQuery.Count() > 0)
```